# Store and retrieve settings for user in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there an easy way to store user settings in an asp.net mvc app? For example, settings such as how often they want notifications, where to send notifications and anything else you can think of that the user would personalize for themselves.

Is there some built in thing in .net that can do this? I'd like to store the settings in the database with a foriegn key that links to that user.

If there is no built in .net features for this, how would I design my database table for settings? (just an example)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you want them to be persistent? If there aren't many of them, store them in a cookie.

If you can't store them in a cookie, then store them in a database table:

```
UserPreferences
---------------
Id
UserId
PreferenceName
Value
```

If you're worried about normalization and all that, then you could always add another table:

```
Preferences
-------------
Id
Name
Type
```

And your UserPreferences table would become:

```
UserPreferences
---------------
Id
UserId
PreferenceId
Value
```

I could go forever on possible tables, or persistence mechanisms. The question is, what sort of preferences are these? Session? Lifetime?

Comment: Lifetime, stuff that will run in the background and utilize the settings stored on the server.

Answer (score 3):

The Built in .Net Membership & Roles engine allows you to store user profile information.

[Here's an intro on getting it running in MVC.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049%28VS.98%29.aspx)

[Here's a sample of someone using the API to talk to the store.](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1327/profile-provider-in-aspnet-mvc/)

[Here's some basics on the .Net Membership & Roles engine...](http://computerscribe.com/blogs/BlogPost?id=11)

[You'll want to focus on the Personalization part of the engine](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111657/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101106-1.aspx#postadlink) (webforms sample but you should be able to adapt).

[If for some reason you need more or to do it a bit differently you can create your own provider...](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103243/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101806-1.aspx#postadlink)

Answer (score 2):

Well you could have a table in the database that will contain the user preferences:

```
Preferences
-----------
Id       <- PK
UserId   <- FK pointing to the User table
Setting1
Setting2
...
```

Comment: @Zerofiz, do you mind elaborating and suggesting a better design?

Comment: Do you expect him to add a new column every time he wants to utilize a new preference?

Comment: @Zerofiz, yes I do because I don't know in advance the type of this setting (string, decimal, datetime, ...). Of course if it is a simple key/value collection where the key and the value are always of the same type two columns would be enough.

Comment: @Darin - I would propose a much simpler table design that would utilize rows to store the settings for a user, therefore allowing him to add a row of data to facilitate the preference instead of making schema changes each and every time.

Comment: @Zerofiz, could you post this suggestion as answer?

Comment: @Darin, I did.  It may need modified to fit into his current database design, but the general idea is there.

Comment: @Zerofiz, so in this design you are allowing the setting to be only of a single type? It could be sufficient but what if different types need to be handled?

Comment: @Darin - yes.  Most likely the column would need to be a varchar, and any conversions would need to be done in code.

Comment: @Zerofiz, while I agree that this could work in the general case I have seen situations where the settings were of different types and queries needed to be performed against those settings. For example find all users who set some reminder date in less then two weeks so that the system can send them some notification email, ... The reminder date was of course a datetime column the database and would allow this kind of queries. If you store all settings as varchar this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @Darin - that's simply not true.  You can perform the same actions on a varchar column, you just need to make the conversions to a datetime in your query.

Comment: @Zerofiz, you will cast strings to dates? While it might work it just feels a bit hacky to me and it might come with an additional overhead. You also might need to take into account date formats between different cultures which could quickly turn into a difficult to handle situation.

Comment: @Darin, why not?  If I know the value will be a date, only stored as a string, I can attempt to make the conversion (albeit catching errors properly).  For me, it's a good trade-off for proper database design.

Comment: I for one see nothing wrong with Darin's design. What Zerofiz is advising here is in my view a lot of premature optimization - especially since the question did not give any details about how flexible the solution should be..... You suggest the most flexible solution possible, but one that will give him quite a few headaches. Instead of going with the obvious answer. Users will probably not add settings by themselves so this much flexibility is pointless